# Sum properties using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, sum

```
DealsThisMonthOpen = deals.Where(deal => deal.DateCreated.Month == date.Month && deal.DealStatus == "Open").Count(),
DealsThisMonthLost = deals.Where(deal => deal.DateCreated.Month == date.Month && deal.DealStatus == "Lost").Count(),
DealsThisMonthWon = deals.Where(deal => deal.DateCreated.Month == date.Month && deal.DealStatus == "Won").Count(),
DealsThisMonth = DealsThisMonthOpen + DealsThisMonthLost + DealsThisMonthWon;
```

The last line is not syntax correct. Is it possible to do it like this or I will have to write query for this Property to calculate sum?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

btw, `Count()` also supports `predicate` argument:
 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535181.aspx

So you can:

```
var a = deals.Count(deal => deal.DateCreated.Month == date.Month && deal.DealStatus == "Open"),
var b = deals.Count(deal => deal.DateCreated.Month == date.Month && deal.DealStatus == "Lost"),
var c = deals.Count(deal => deal.DateCreated.Month == date.Month && deal.DealStatus == "Won"),

new foobar
{
    DealsThisMonthOpen = a,
    DealsThisMonthLost = b,
    DealsThisMonthWon = c,
    DealsThisMonth = a + b + c
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I'm missing something, but that should definitely work.

The `Count(`) method returns an `int` so `DealsThisMonthOpen`, `DealsThisMonthLost`, and `DealsThisMonthWon` are all integer values. `DealsThisMonth` is just the sum of those three integer values.

You could also make it a little cleaner (unless you need the three distinct values for something else later:

```
var dealsThisMonth = deals
    .Count(d => d.DateCreated.Month == date.Month
        && (new string[] { "Open", "Lost", "Won" }).Contains(d.DealStatus));
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered an extension method?  Where you provide the sum feature.