# sum of an element of items using one linq command

Tags: c#, linq

I have a List ListOfGames where VideoGame is:

```
public class VideoGame{
   public string Title;
   public string Platform;
   public string PublishingCompany;
   public int InStock; //this is how many that we have in stock
   public decimal Price;
   public int GameID; //this is the ID of a specific title. For example: all DOOM games have   id of say 234 regardless of platform.
   //etc.
}
```

I want to get the total amount of VideoGames we have in stock for a certain game using a simple Sum Query with LINQ.

I tried:

```
int stock = ListOfGames.Sum(e=>e.InStock == GameID); 
//GameID is a param that refers to the id of the game.
```

but that does not return the correct value.

I looked at this question: [Sum properties using LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3133112/sum-properties-using-linq), but it does not help. Any ideas on how to get the sum of the quantity of all the games in stock for a certain GameID?

Comment: I might be missing something, but InStock is unlikely to match GameID

Comment: So you don't really want the "sum of the quantity of all the games in stock", then?

Comment: question has been edited. sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
int stock = ListOfGames.Where(x=>x.Id == GameID).Sum(x=>x.Instock);
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is my suggestion:

```
int stock = ListOfGames.Where(e => e.GameID == GameID).Sum(e => e.InStock);
```

Answer (score 2):

Surely you just neeed

```
var sumOfStock = ListOfGames.Sum(vg => vg.InStock);
```

since `InStock` is the property you wish to sum?

Comment: But that sums up **all** games, not the ones with a special `GameID` as OP asked for.

Comment: I failed to appreciate from the question text that OP was asking for that.

Answer (score 2):

In your query, you you comparing the number of games in stock (InStock) to the GameID parameter, which I'm sure is not what you intend do.

To get just the sum of all games in in stock:

```
int stock = ListOfGames.Sum(e=>e.InStock);
```

However, it looks like you also want to filter by a specific game?  In that case, how does GameID correspond to your VideoGame object?  If you had an actual ID field on the VideoGame class, you could get the sum like this:

```
int stock = ListOfGames.Where(e=>e.ID == GameID).Sum(e=>e.InStock);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int stock = ListOfGames.Where(e => e.GameId == GameID).Sum(e => e.InStock);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to query for the sum of all `VideoGame` that has `InStock` equal to a specific `GameId` then try:

```
 var query = from game in ListOfGames
                  where game.InStock == GameId
                  select game;
 int sum = query.Sum();
```